# Terminal freezing while trying to push local git repo to GitHub

Tags: git, github, terminal

I'm trying to push my file from a local git repository to a GitHub via terminal.

When i insert:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/vbavinicius/git-basics.git
git push -u origin master
```

i insert my username and when going to insert my password the terminal freezes.

Anyone knows the solution?

Sorry for bad english, i'm non english speaker.

Comment: Thanks you my friend, i didn't realize the terminal don't show password characters, i thought that was freeze. really thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it just does not echo your password back? Try just blindly typing and press enter. Even better, set up SSH keys.